# Postgres simple query failure with no error

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying Postgres with node.

I created a table `test` with only one column `test` which has only one row `test`

In my app.ts I create connection (a Pool) and set it in app.

```
this.pool = new pg.Pool({
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      database: process.env.DB_BASE,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: Number(process.env.DB_POST),
});
this.app.set('pool', this.pool);
```

I checked the `process.env.DB_*` values with `console.log()`, they are goods.

And my test controller:

```
static readonly test = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const pool = await req.app.get('pool').connect();
    pool.query('SELECT test FROM public.test')
    .then((res: any) => {
      res.status(200).json(res);
    })
    .catch((e: any) => {
      res.status(404).json(e);
      // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-template
      console.log('e1 ' + e.error || e.stack); // got e1 undefined
    });
}
```

NB: the query `SELECT test FROM public.test` in pgAdmin 4 works and returns my one row "test"

May I missed something ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving an error?  You are using a mix of asynchronous code and your promise link has a .catch to log the error.  However any error received in the connect() method isn't being caught since you are using 'Await'.  Wrap your await code into a try / catch block to see if your connection method is kicking back an error.  Or promise link it with the rest of your code.   Add the below:

```
try {
  const pool = await req.app.get('pool').connect();
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Any error occuring during your connect() method will then help you further investigate.

UPDATE:
If you are just trying to simply execute a single query, you can use pool itself instead of creating a connection client:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool({ INSERT CONNECTION DETAILS })
pool.query(select * from test, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('Error executing query', err.stack)
  }
  console.log(result.rows[0])
})
```

Comment: No errors. And in the second catch the error is empty